# Replace string in a column using query in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, str-replace

In one of my oracle tables, in one column in every row there is a string 'House Name'. I need to  replace it with 'House Number'. Can I execute an update query to find and replace this string in all rows.Or is there any built in function for that.

Comment: yu can do it with update query

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following from [Tech on the Net](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/replace.php) may help:

> REPLACE('User House Name is ABC', 'House Name', 'House Number');
>
> would return 'User House Number is ABC'
>
> REPLACE('123tech123', '123'); would return 'tech'
>
> REPLACE('222tech', '2', '3'); would return '333tech'
>
> REPLACE('0000123', '0');          would return '123'
>
> REPLACE('House Name', 'House Name', 'House Number');  would return
>   'House Number'

Comment: @Tom Sebastian use this in your Select or update query... will work for you

Comment: Thanks. I used REPLACE function like this:  **update PATIENT set ADDRESS = REPLACE(ADDRESS , 'House Name', 'House Number');**   then ADDRESS column of all rows get updated correctly.

Comment: Hi, when quoting from somewhere else please ensure that you grant them credit; it's plagiarism if you don't.

Answer (score 4):

Just execute :

```
UPDATE <TABLE-NAME> SET <COLUMN-NAME> = 'House Number' WHERE <COLUMN_MAME> = 'House Name'
```

This of course will work only if the column contains this string only. Otherwise you should use the replace function as answered by Fayeq in your update statement above

```
UPDATE <TABLE-NAME> SET <COLUMN-NAME> = REPLACE('House Name', 'Name', 'Number') WHERE <COLUMN_MAME> = 'House Name'
```

**EDIT** :

You can omit the `WHERE` clause if all rows contain the same string (House Number)

Comment: Ok. can we avoid the where clause?

Comment: Actually you can unless some rows contain another string (which then will override them as well).

Comment: i meant to use like this. **REPLACE(<COLUMN_NAME>, 'House Name', 'House Number')** .I'm not sure but it's working for me.

Comment: why does it take forever to update a single value